# fetch api sends scroll to top of div

Tags: javascript

im using the fetch api and when my data loads the scroll of the div it loads in gets put to the top. i tried scrolling back to the last div you see before the fetch but that also doesn't work.
im trying to make an infinite scroll.
what i want is for the scroll to stay in the same position instead of jump to the top.

my code to increase the amount of messages loaded:

```
    const msgs = document.getElementById('messages');
setInterval(() => {
    if (document.getElementById('messages').scrollTop <=  100) {
            viewamnt = viewamnt + 100;
            getstuff(viewamnt)
        }
    if (document.getElementById('messages').scrollTop >=  100) {
            viewamnt = 50;
    }
}, 600);
```

my code to fetch data:

```
function getstuff(viewamnt){
        var lastRead = document.querySelector('.chats').lastElementChild.previousSibling.id;
        fetch("includes/load-chats.php?room=<?php echo $room?>&amnt="+viewamnt, {
            method: "POST",
        })
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((text) => {
            document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML = text;
        })
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like an infinite scroll solution as you are just returning the same data + more from the API each time. Infinite scrolls usually return paged data, e.g. on load it'll return page 1 (say 20 results), then as you scroll it'll then ask the API for the next 10/20 results (depending on how much data you want populated each time). The response data is then just appended to what you have existing.

I suspect your UI is scrolling to the top because it's recreating all the data each time.

Comment: @TimBJames i tried using insertAdjacentHTML but it still scrolls